# Is it possible to use DataAnnotations with Interfaces inheritance?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, inheritance, interface, data-annotations

*not performing the validation in PersonaFisica* 
..

> Blockquote

```
 [MetadataType(typeof(IValidationPersona))]
public  class Persona : Entidad, IValidationPersona
{    
    public string Mail { get; set; }
    public string Telefono { get; set; }
}
[MetadataType(typeof(IValidationPersonaFisica))]
public class PersonaFisica : Persona, IValidationPersonaFisica
{
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public string Apellido { get; set; }
}

public interface IValidationPersona
{
    [DisplayName("Persona -- Email")]
     string Mail { get; set; }

    [RegularExpression(@"^\d+$", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ValidationMessages),   ErrorMessageResourceName = "SoloNumeros")]
    string Telefono { get; set; }
}

public interface IValidationPersona
{
    [DisplayName("Persona -- Email")]
    string Mail { get; set; }

    [RegularExpression(@"^\d+$", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ValidationMessages),   ErrorMessageResourceName = "SoloNumeros")]
    string Telefono { get; set; }
}
```

> > validation does not work with inheritance in interfaces, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This feature is not implemented in the framework for couple of good reasons. Please refer to this MSDN forum [DataAnnotations in Interfaces](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adonetefx/thread/1748587a-f13c-4dd7-9fec-c8d57014632c/)